# Kafka multiple consumer instances does not receive message

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

i have an app that i want to open in multiple instances and i need each instance to receive the message.Actually each instance receives message only if the instance have different group id.I put more partitions than actual instances and it does not work.The app works as consumer/producer at the same time.
code:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfigForDepartment {


    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, MessageEventForDepartment> producerFactoryForDepartment() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("MARCEL")
                .partitions(10)
                .compact()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, MessageEventForDepartment> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactoryForDepartment());
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

/*    @Value(value = "${kafka.configId}")
    private String configId;*/

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, MessageEventForDepartment> consumerFactoryForDepartments() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        //props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, configId);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(MessageEventForDepartment.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MessageEventForDepartment>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactoryForDepartments() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MessageEventForDepartment> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryForDepartments());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DepartmentKafkaService {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "MARCEL" , groupId = "ren",containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryForDepartments")
    public void listenGroupFoo(MessageEventForDepartment message) {
    ...
```

Do you know why this happening because i thought if i will have more partitions per group than instances this will work?

Answer (score 0):

That is how Kafka is designed; for multiple instances to get all the records, they must be in different groups.

When they are in the same group, the partitions are distributed across the active instances. Each time a new member arrives, or leaves, the partitions are rebalanced